# Monitoring software that monitors servers and applications

Tags: monitoring

I am looking for software (like Nagios) that also can monitor my applications. 
Is there a software solution that monitors both the servers and the applications on those servers?

[image]

Comment: How do you want to monitor applications? Monitor for what? Just that they are running? Do you want a [tag:gratis] solution, or do you have a budget in mind?

Comment: And which o/s is/are your server(s) running? That probably makes a difference when monitoring applications

Comment: Free preferrably (of course) but will entertain paid solution.  Cloud or on prem.  Servers and applications (which are mostly Java apps) run on Windows and Red Hat Linux.  Just need to see if application succeed or fail or on in progress.

Comment: Then it would help if you can state a budget - would $10/year or $1k/server/year be acceptable? We can use your budget to rule in/out some solutions. The more detail you give us, the better we can help you

Comment: How will you determine application success/fail? This sounds very specific to me, needing a tailor made solution

Comment: Applications return 0 on successful, anything else is failed.  Budget is limited to $1000/year.  Yes, this seems to me to be a 'tailored' solution that may need to be developed "in-house".  But as an example I gave Nagios, which would work if it only could monitor Java applications.

Comment: "Applications return 0" ... so you need something to launch it and record the result, maybe writing to a text file (or send an email, etc ...)? Unless the app can be modified to do so. Maybe you can use Jenkins to launch the app(s) and record the result, and Nagios to detect that the Jenkins server is running?  From your profile, I would suggest (Python) scripting something for the app(s), plus Nagios. But, you haven't told us how often the apps run, how often the result should be checked? Is it once, or repeated? There is a lot of detail missing here ...

Comment: The application results are stored in a database table.  Just need to monitor whether the applications are running, successfully completed or failed to complete.  Sure, it would be nice to start/stop an application but that is not required.  Just a dashboard view of the applications. I've added a Nagios dashboard to the question.  it does not have to be as sophisticated as the image.  But Nagios focuses on the system level.  I'd like application level as well (unless there is a Nagios plugin I am not aware of that does that).

Comment: As far as apps run frequency, how often results checked, etc.  The preference is I would like the dashboard to be able to look at my environment at any and all times.

Comment: I really reckon that you will have to code it yourself.  Use [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) for  the dashboard, forget Nagios & just ping the server(s) regulalry

Comment: I believe (as Mawg pointed out) that such a product does not yet exist. I’ve only seen products that do one or the other. Thanks for your time everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynatrace is APM and infrastructure monitoring solution. It supports a [wide range of technologies](https://www.dynatrace.com/technologies/) (including java related stack). It works both as a SaaS and on-premise

Sadly it is not free, but from my experience is worth the price for big deployments.

Comment: Does this tool live in the cloud or can it be deployed on-prem?

Comment: It provides both flavors.

Answer (score 1):

After much discussion, the consensus is that such a product does not exist and that it may actually be preferable to develop the product oneself.

Comment: Please also accept your answer (you may have to wait before you can do so), as this will help others in future. Good luck with your app. Personally, I would go with Jenkins & Python.